Creating a Device Tree Binding for LSM6DS3TR-C (only i2c nodes accepted issue)
I am trying to use the LSM6DS3TR-C IMU on the Seeed xiao sense board using Zephyr. Through discussions I have seen that the bindings of the examples only work in particular conditions so as a result I am making the device tree/binding from the ground up.
I found a st,lsm6dsx.yaml binding from the Linux Kernel Archives. When using this .yaml file I get the error: "only i2c nodes accepted" when I use the binding in the compatible section in my overlay file as shown below:
&i2c0 {
    compatible = "nordic,nrf-twim";
    /* Cannot be used together with spi0. */
    status = "okay";
    pinctrl-0 = <&i2c0_default>;
    pinctrl-1 = <&i2c0_sleep>;
    pinctrl-names = "default", "sleep";
    clock-frequency = <I2C_BITRATE_FAST>;
    label = "I2C0";

    imu@6a{
        compatible = "st,lsm6dsx";
        reg = <0x6a>;
        label = "IMU";
        vdd-supply=<&regulator_imu>;
        vddio-supply=<&regulator_imu>;
        st,pullups;
        
    };
};

The contents of the binding file are below:
# SPDX-License-Identifier: (GPL-2.0 OR BSD-2-Clause)
%YAML 1.2
---
$id: http://devicetree.org/schemas/iio/imu/st,lsm6dsx.yaml#
$schema: http://devicetree.org/meta-schemas/core.yaml#

title: STM 6-axis (acc + gyro) IMU Mems sensors

maintainers:
  - Lorenzo Bianconi <lorenzo@kernel.org>

description:
  Devices have both I2C and SPI interfaces.

properties:
  compatible:
    oneOf:
      - enum:
          - st,lsm6ds3
          - st,lsm6ds3h
          - st,lsm6dsl
          - st,lsm6dsm
          - st,ism330dlc
          - st,lsm6dso
          - st,asm330lhh
          - st,lsm6dsox
          - st,lsm6dsr
          - st,lsm6ds3tr-c
          - st,ism330dhcx
          - st,lsm9ds1-imu
          - st,lsm6ds0
          - st,lsm6dsrx
          - st,lsm6dst
          - st,lsm6dsop
          - st,lsm6dsv
          - st,lsm6dso16is
      - items:
          - enum:
              - st,asm330lhhx
              - st,asm330lhhxg1
          - const: st,lsm6dsr
      - items:
          - const: st,lsm6dstx
          - const: st,lsm6dst
      - items:
          - const: st,lsm6dsv16x
          - const: st,lsm6dsv
      - items:
          - const: st,ism330is
          - const: st,lsm6dso16is
      - items:
          - const: st,asm330lhb
          - const: st,asm330lhh

  reg:
    maxItems: 1

  interrupts:
    minItems: 1
    maxItems: 2
    description:
      Supports up to 2 interrupt lines via the INT1 and INT2 pins.

  vdd-supply:
    description: if defined provides VDD power to the sensor.

  vddio-supply:
    description: if defined provides VDD IO power to the sensor.

  st,drdy-int-pin:
    $ref: /schemas/types.yaml#/definitions/uint32
    description: |
      The pin on the package that will be used to signal data ready
    enum:
      - 1
      - 2

  st,pullups:
    type: boolean
    description: enable/disable internal i2c controller pullup resistors.

  st,disable-sensor-hub:
    type: boolean
    description:
      Enable/disable internal i2c controller slave autoprobing at bootstrap.
      Disable sensor-hub is useful if i2c controller clock/data lines are
      connected through a pull-up with other chip lines (e.g. SDO/SA0).

  drive-open-drain:
    type: boolean
    description:
      The interrupt/data ready line will be configured as open drain, which
      is useful if several sensors share the same interrupt line.

  wakeup-source:
    $ref: /schemas/types.yaml#/definitions/flag

  mount-matrix:
    description: an optional 3x3 mounting rotation matrix

required:
  - compatible
  - reg

allOf:
  - $ref: /schemas/iio/iio.yaml#
  - $ref: /schemas/spi/spi-peripheral-props.yaml#

unevaluatedProperties: false

examples:
  - |
    #include <dt-bindings/interrupt-controller/irq.h>
    i2c {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;

        imu@6b {
            compatible = "st,lsm6dsm";
            reg = <0x6b>;
            interrupt-parent = <&gpio0>;
            interrupts = <0 IRQ_TYPE_EDGE_RISING>;
        };
    };
...

The reference file doesn't have the I2C reference in the all of ref section, but makes reference to using the binding with i2c. So is this binding compatible with I2C or not? From my research it is not.
IF I were to implement an I2C version, how would I go about know what base properties I would need?
If you think there is a better way of implementing the the LSM6DS3TR-C operation then lets have a discussion around that.
Thanks All

While both Linux and Zephyr use devicetrees and yaml bindings for them, they do diverge significantly in how these are actually used. Notably, Zephyr actually enforced bindings as part of building an image while Linux uses them purely for documentation. As such, taking a Linux devicetree fragment or binding typically will not work.
For this specific part, it appears support already exists within Zephyr, even for your board: https://github.com/zephyrproject-rtos/zephyr/blob/main/boards%2Fseeed%2Fxiao_ble%2Fxiao_ble_nrf52840_sense.dts#L40
Here, the IMU is declared and uses the "st,lsm6dsl" compatible driver (which should work with the LSM6DS3TR-C as well. There is a binding for this here: https://github.com/zephyrproject-rtos/zephyr/blob/main/dts%2Fbindings%2Fsensor%2Fst%2Clsm6dsl-i2c.yaml . So, you should just need to make sure CONFIG_SENSOR is set and the driver should be available via the sensor API.
Just a note to the exact error you encountered, I believe that's a result of the binding not declaring the on-bus property, which tells the binding is meant to appear on specific buses: https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/build/dts/bindings-syntax.html#on-bus . Again, Zephyr and Linux bindings are different so it doesn't appear the Linux one uses this.
